# Averaging function isn't averaging instead it's resetting

Tags: python, function, for-loop, average, python-3.3

I'm attempting to utilize TeamTreehouse learning subscription & this Starting Out With Programming Logic And Design book to attempt learning programming & python.

Goal: Combine the input received via pass by reference in line 12 to then add each subsequent input passed in to testScoreAverage in addition to the previous value. Instead it's just keeping one value not a running total.

I've added comments indicating my errors/understanding of the code line by line

I really think I'm somehow setting my variable to 0 by setting them equal to datatype int but I don't understand how that could be because I've been able to do this in the past?

```
#///////////////Defining Variables/////////////
testScore1=0
testScore2=0
testScore3=0
testScore4=0
testScore5=0
tests=5
testScoreAverage=0
#///////////////Defining Variables/////////////

#///////////////calcAverage Function/////////////

#L2g2h: defines function & receives current testScore int value
def calcAverage(testScore):

    #L2g2h: initiates variable testScoreAverage as an int value type (but doesn't set it to any value)
    testScoreAverage=int()

    #L2g2h: again initiating a variable, variable testScores, to int value type (but not setting it to any numeric value)
    testScores=int()

    #L2g2h: for loop starting
    for i in range(1, tests + 1):

        #L2g2h: testScores is set equal to the current testScores value PLUS the current value of testScore to become a running total
        testScores=testScores+testScore

        #L2g2h: testScoreAverage is dividing the current testScores value by the current counter variable i's value to come up with an average
        testScoreAverage=testScores/i

    #////NEED TO SET NUMBER TO HOLD ONLY 2 DECIMAL PLACES
    #L2g2h: print out the current testScoreAverage
    print("Your test score average so far is ", float(testScoreAverage))

#///////////////calcAverage Function/////////////

#///////////////determineGrade Function/////////////    
def determineGrade(testScore):
#    for i in range(1, tests + 1):     
    if testScore>=90 and testScore <= 100:
        print("Your test score grade is an A.")
    elif testScore>=80 and testScore <= 89:
        print("Your test score grade is a B.")
    elif testScore>=70 and testScore <= 79:
        print("Your test score grade is a C.")
    elif testScore>=60 and testScore <= 69:
        print("Your test score grade is a D.")
    elif testScore<=60:
        print("Your test score grade is a F.")
    else:
        print("That is invalid.")
#///////////////determineGrade Function/////////////
for i in range(1, tests + 1):
    testScore=int(input("Enter test score #" + str(i)))
    calcAverage(testScore)
    determineGrade(testScore)
```

Comment: `testScores=int()` *does* set it to a value; `int()` returns `0`. Just write `testScores = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `calcAverage` once at each iteration in the last `for` loop. You should calculate the average only after the user inputs all score values.

Append your values to a list first, then, after the user has entered all values, calculate the average:

```
#///////////////Defining Variables/////////////
testScore1=0
testScore2=0
testScore3=0
testScore4=0
testScore5=0
tests=5
testScoreAverage=0
#///////////////Defining Variables/////////////

#///////////////calcAverage Function/////////////
def calcAverage(testScore):
    testScoreAverage=int()
    testScoreAverage= sum(testScore)/len(testScore)
#////NEED TO SET NUMBER TO HOLD ONLY 2 DECIMAL PLACES
    print("Your test score average so far is ", float(testScoreAverage))
    return testScoreAverage
#///////////////calcAverage Function/////////////

#///////////////determineGrade Function/////////////    
def determineGrade(testScore):
#    for i in range(1, tests + 1):     
    if testScore>=90 and testScore <= 100:
        print("Your test score grade is an A.")
    elif testScore>=80 and testScore <= 89:
        print("Your test score grade is a B.")
    elif testScore>=70 and testScore <= 79:
        print("Your test score grade is a C.")
    elif testScore>=60 and testScore <= 69:
        print("Your test score grade is a D.")
    elif testScore<=60:
        print("Your test score grade is a F.")
    else:
        print("That is invalid.")
#///////////////determineGrade Function/////////////

scores =[]
for i in range(1, tests + 1):
    scores.append(int(input("Enter test score #" + str(i)+" ")))

average = calcAverage(scores)
determineGrade(average)
```

Notice that, to calculate the average in a list, you can use `sum` function to sum all values in this list, then divide by the list length, using `len(list)`

If you want to determine the grade for **each** score, you can iterate over the list that contais the score and determineGrade for each one, like this:

```
for score in scores: #scores is the list
    determineGrade(score)
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much Rafael. I havent used/been introduced to lists so far on my learning course - how do I put my list items through the determineGrade function then to get the grade for each of the individual 5?

Comment: In order to get the grade for each individual score, do a for loop and test it to each one. I will edit the post to show you how

Answer (score 0):

Correct, re-initializing variables will clear a previous value. Also, in python you don't always need to initialize or declare variables, research when and where you do.

The code below makes use of a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to store each of the scores.  Then `calcAverage()` can average over the whole list all at once. So at any point you can get the current average.

Also be careful with local and global variables, it is best to only use local variables within a function by clearly passing in necessary arguments and returning specific values.  The name of variables were changed slightly to exemplify the differences in local (function) vs global (script) scope.

As a recommendation, `determineGrade()` should only return the letter grade, and the `print` statement should be at the script level.  This allows reuse of the function. For example, to get the grade for the individual test and the average (see code).

```
#### ///////////////Defining Variables/////////////
tests = 5
testScores = []

#///////////////calcAverage Function/////////////
def calcAverage(scores):
    return float(sum(scores))/float(len(scores))

#///////////////determineGrade Function/////////////    
def determineGrade(score):
    #python allows inequality range comparisons!
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif 80 <= score <= 89:
        return "B"
    elif 70 <= score <= 79:
        return "C"
    elif 60 <= score <= 69:
        return "D"
    elif score < 60:
        return "F"
    else:
        return "invalid"

#///////////////main script/////////////
for i in range(1, tests + 1):
    testScore = int(input("Enter test score #" + str(i) + ' '))
    testGrade = determineGrade(testScore)

    testScores.append(testScore)

    testScoreAverage = calcAverage(testScores)
    testGradeAverage = determineGrade(testScoreAverage)

    print("Your test grade is " + str(testGrade))
    print("Your test score average so far is " + str(testScoreAverage))
    print("Your test grade average so far is " + str(testGradeAverage))
    print # just to make the output nicer
```

output

```
Enter test score #1 100
Your test grade is A
Your test score average so far is 100.0
Your test grade average so far is A

Enter test score #2 50
Your test grade is F
Your test score average so far is 75.0
Your test grade average so far is C

Enter test score #3 89
Your test grade is B
Your test score average so far is 79.6666666667
Your test grade average so far is invalid

Enter test score #4 90
Your test grade is A
Your test score average so far is 82.25
Your test grade average so far is B

Enter test score #5 45
Your test grade is F
Your test score average so far is 74.8
Your test grade average so far is C
```

Keep learning python! It is an awesome, succinct & powerful language!